# Reducing code for same functionality for multiple elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-lists

How to reduce bunch of code and set function  setShowMenu somewhere in one line ?

```
<li className="listItem" onClick={() => setShowMenu(!showMenu)}>HOME</li>
<li className="listItem" onClick={() => setShowMenu(!showMenu)}>PRODUCTS</li>
<li className="listItem" onClick={() => setShowMenu(!showMenu)}>ABOUT</li>
<li className="listItem" onClick={() => setShowMenu(!showMenu)}>CONTACT</li>
```

Comment: It seems odd that all of those menu items do the same thing...?

Comment: Yes, it doing same thing for all listItem, on mobile device after click one of listItem, the navigation is going to be disappeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways. One approach is to use an array:

```
// Somewhere it's created only once
const menu = ["HOME", "PRODUCTS", "ABOUT", "CONTACT"];
```

And since they all use the same handler, create just one rather than four (perhaps in the component render):

```
const onClick = () => setShowMenu(!showMenu);
```

Then

```
{menu.map(item => <li key={item} className="listItem" onClick={onClick}>{item}</li>)}
```

Note the `key`, since this is an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
const lists = ["HOME","PRODUCTS","ABOUT","CONTACT"].map(list => <li className="listItem" onClick={() => setShowMenu(!showMenu)}>{{list}}</li> )

return (
    <div>
       {{lists}}
    </div>
)
```